# Disk Not Ejected Properly on an external hard drive I no longer own

Tags: hard-drive, external-disk, eject

Just wondering if anyone knows what I can do to stop this message popping up (for a specific drive, if possible)? I had an external hard drive that, because I was throwing it away, I didn't concern myself with ejecting it properly. I expected this message would come up once and I would click "close" and be done with it. The hard drive is now long gone (so I can't just plug it back in and eject it properly), but I am still constantly getting the warning pop up that it wasn't ejected. Thanks in advance for any advice on how to disable the warning about this particular hard drive.

Comment: Can you edit your question to include the output of "diskutil list" in terminal?

Comment: and `ls -la /Volumes` please?

Comment: I actually don't know what either of these things are. Sorry, I'm not very technically savvy.